# Changes in the theme editor doesn't update project?

Tags: android, mobile

so I am running the latest version of android studio, and I am a bit confused about how the theme editor works. I have selected a different theme from the options, but android studio isn't updating everything to fit the theme. styles.xml looks the same as it was before as well as the colours used are the same. I've selected a theme with no action bar but the preview doesn't seem to have updated as well.

I was under the presumption that any changes in the theme editor will automatically update to  the project, so I dont have to go to the xml code and change it all. Do I still need to do that even after using the theme editor?

Comment: Try to click the refresh button of the preview. It updates your window.

Comment: You press R on the preview page right? I've already done that, and it doesn't change anything. The styles.xml and colors.xml are also the same as they were before, regardless of any new themes I select in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

There's a refresh button for the Preview window which, when clicked, updated and displays the correct theme.

Answer (score 0):

that option only gives you a preview on the theme, it doesn't change the code 
to do that you should just pick a theme from that option and do it manually and it should work

Comment: So the only purpose of theme editor is to just preview what things might look like with the theme selected? I am a bit confused, why make them themes if there is no way to apply what you've made to the whole project?

Comment: i used the theme editor before and it doesn't work with me so i had to do it with code
dont worry it is not too hard anyone can do it